# How To Get All Plugin Related JARs in Grails?

Tags: grails, plugins, jar, war

I use `"grails war -nojars"` to get a smaller grails war file. Then I need to get all the related plugin jars and put them in the *Tomcat*'s lib.

Does *Grails* provide some solution to get all the plugin related jars and the external jars by typing "grails ....."? If not, can any one help tell me how to get these jars without unpacking the war file and copying them from the `/web-inf/plugins`?

Answer (score 0):

I could not find any form of command that did this, but it is quite simple to do with a few lines of shell code:

you would need to do do grails war twice - once without the nojars

When doing a full war after completed run this:

```
unzip -l warname.war |grep jar|awk '{print $NF}'
```

This will list all the jars which you could store into a variable or something for your next bit to generate what jars to put into tomcat

```
unzip -l testjenkins-0.1.war |grep jar|awk '{print $NF}'|sed -e "s:^WEB-INF/lib/::g"
```

run above to remove all WEB-INF/lib/ from the list returned.